# What data structure is a List interface in Java?

Tags: java, list, interface

I'm interested in knowing what data structure is a List interface in Java and what is the similar  thing in C that best matches it if any.

Comment: Javadoc should be best starting place : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html . Lists are like arrays (which also exists in java), but have more features like automatically increases size as needed. Internally most lists are implemented as one containing an array, which is automatically replaced by a bigger array, if the list size grows.

Comment: So I should treat it as a dynamic array and all the operations of arrays will be applicable to it?

Comment: Arrays and List are different in Java. To see operations on a list, refer to the javadocs referenced above (or of a different version of Java you may be using). For arrays refer to this doc:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 3):

It's an interface, not an implementation, which means the actual data structure is not fixed - it depends on the implementation.

The most important features of a List is that it can retain the order in which elements are added.

If you wanted such a thing in C, you'd have to build it yourself (and I have done in the past).  You'd likely use one of the patterns that Java actually used for implementation.

1. Linked-list.  Elements are chained together, either singly-linked or doubly-linked, depending on requirements.
2. Array-based. Simple enough, though you'll perhaps need to provide for expansion of the array when the list is full (so you'll want to wrap the array in another structure).

The tradeoffs are like this:  the linked-list solution allows insertions and removals with constant cost, whereas an array solution likely requires moving data for insertion and removal anywhere except the tail.  The array solution allows constant-time indexing, whereas finding an entry by index is O(n) for the linked list.

The Java equivalents are called LinkedList and ArrayList. Both of those classes implement the List interface.

Answer (score 0):

A list is a generic term. Just like a variable holds a number for example, a list is there to hold more items than one and hold them in a special way. Now this is special way is the implementation you want with your list which will determine its data structure. C only has arrays and structs, so the closest example is an array, however to achieve close to what a list is in Java, you'd have to create it yourself like a linked-list.